# How can I make particles collide with each other?

Tags: particles

Is this possible? If it is, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a quick sample file I made: [DOWNLOAD SAMPLE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw3gozydpzelp0u/quick%20sample%20.blend?dl=0)

Notice the particles merge in with each other, instead of bouncing off of each other. I want them to behave like marbles would if they were dumped into a cup. They'd bounce, settle, and create a pile within the cup.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us that, we can help more easily.

Comment: Say, if you're trying to fill up a cup with particles: sand particles, rice, beads, etc.

They would have to be affected by gravity and interact with each other like real grains of sand/beads. I chose particles because you can give them a starting speed from an emitter and precisely direct their movement until gravity finally takes them down, you know?

Answer (score 5):

There is an Add-on called [Molecular](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/). It makes the particles act as *Rigid Bodies*. The particles can be linked to each other as well.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5QkPnPDcfc) is a teaser trailer that the coder made.

Just download the .zip, go to *File > User Preferences > Addons* and click *Install from File*. Select the .zip. Check it to enable it. If you need more help installing, let me know.

Comment: Great to hear that they made v1.0.3 for Blender 2.77. I'll have to give it another try.

A while back, I tried to perform the same thing in my OP with Molecular and 2.74... but this was the result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyf4aDn08UY. The particles wouldn't sit still at all -- rising and jittery to the very end.

Comment: @Jesse Glad to help! If my answer does indeed work, please consider accepting it. If it needs modification, let me know.