# Making objects fall into a pile with Particle Emitter

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I am trying to make objects fall onto a plane and actually pile up like normal objects would.

Instead of that, the objects fall, bounce around a few times, and end up merging with each other until they're all totally flat on the plane:

[image]

I've tried many different settings in Physics for both the plane and the cube, I've even tried to play with Molecular add-on but I couldn't find what settings relate to "Particle Self-Collision" in Blender and/or Molecular.

End goal:

Being able to create a pile of objects that looks realistic (as if objects were dumped on the ground from a container) as such (bills only, not the coins):

[image]

Note: There are some similar threads around but the website "blenderartists" seems to be down as I write this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand if that's the same thing - I have to emit thousands of objects before I turn them to separate objects with physics?

Comment: You could use an array modifier or duplicate an object, but you could do it with a particle system to begin with as well. Just hit `convert` in the modifier stack for the particle system and it will make separate objects for you (of course make the particle emitter use a(n) object(s) first). Then you could do what the linked answer says. If you just need the pile at the end, you could join it all into one object after the rigid body simulation is done.

Comment: I don't mind marking it as a duplicate, since it solved my problem, but is it really the same if I am interested in getting this result while not converting the Particle System?

Comment: Related (although the first isn't very useful): https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68820/28015 https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55824/28015